# ACCESS: calculate timestamp difference between rows

Tags: sql, ms-access

Here is the data I am working with in MS Access from a system tracking when a agent makes system changes:

```
|agentid|eventtype|reasoncode|eventdatetimelocal   |
|1830   |2        |32762     |01/01/2014 7:11:44 PM|
|1830   |3        |0         |01/01/2014 7:13:46 PM|
|1830   |2        |32762     |01/01/2014 7:14:55 PM|
|1833   |2        |0         |01/01/2014 7:11:35 PM|
|1833   |3        |32762     |01/01/2014 7:13:25 PM|
```

I need to determine the number of seconds which elapsed between rows by agent. I would also like to preserve the detail of the eventtype and reasoncode.

I tried joining on a subqry but it's not working:

```
SELECT sub1.agentid, 
       sub1.eventtype, 
       sub1.reasoncode,
       sub1.eventdatetimelocal, 
       (sub1.next_timestamp-sub1.eventdatetimelocal) AS duration
FROM (SELECT i.agentid, 
      eventdatetimelocal, 
      eventtype, 
      reasoncode, (SELECT
                        Min([eventdatetimelocal]) 
                   FROM state_detail_tbl 
                   WHERE [eventdatetimelocal] > i.eventdatetimelocal
                   ) AS next_timestamp 
     FROM state_detail_tbl AS i 
     WHERE i.eventdatetimelocal BETWEEN #01/01/2014# AND #01/31/2014#
)  AS sub1;
```

Comment: What your expected output from the sample data be?

Comment: I would expect something along the lines of: agentid, eventype1, reasoncode1, eventdatetimelocal1, eventdatetimelocal2, eventtype2, reasoncode2, seconds. This way I have the punchin, punchout, the events and the reasoncodes and the duration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received an error from the query below stating something along the lines of "this query can only return a maximum of one row". But the query along with this reference: [Calculating time difference between activity timestamps in a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20339890/calculating-time-difference-between-activity-timestamps-in-a-query) gave me what I needed which I am listing below for reference. I decided that my initial needs were too broad and so I simplified the query to return the bare minimum data needed to bring the timestamp up to the previous row. I can step another query in with datediff to figure out the seconds. It takes awhile for this to process but it works and can run overnight if required.

```
SELECT i.agentid, i.eventtype, i.reasoncode, eventdatetimelocal, (SELECT
Min([eventdatetimelocal]) FROM state_detail_subqry WHERE agentid = i.agentid
AND [eventdatetimelocal]>i.[eventdatetimelocal]) AS next_timestamp
FROM state_detail_subqry AS i
ORDER BY agentid, eventdatetimelocal;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query

```
SELECT sub1.agentid, 
       sub1.eventtype, 
       sub1.reasoncode,
       sub1.eventdatetimelocal, 
       (SELECT TOP 1 sub2.eventdatetimelocal - sub1.eventdatetimelocal 
        FROM state_detail_tbl AS sub2 
        WHERE sub1.agentid=sub2.agentid
              AND sub2.eventdatetimelocal > sub1.eventdatetimelocal 
        ORDER BY sub2.eventdatetimelocal) AS duration

FROM state_detail_tbl sub1
WHERE (SELECT TOP 1 eventdatetimelocal 
       FROM state_detail_tbl AS s3 
       WHERE sub1.agentid=s3.agentid 
             AND s3.eventdatetimelocal > sub1.eventdatetimelocal) Is Not Null
AND sub1.eventdatetimelocal BETWEEN #01/01/2014# AND #01/31/2014#
ORDER BY sub1.agentid, sub1.eventdatetimelocal;
```